# In which case the socket connects to itself which has the same source and destination address and port?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, linux-kernel, network-programming

I met a case that lsof output is as following:

TCP node045.XXXX.com:41789->node045.XXXX.com:41789 (ESTABLISHED)

The program connects to itself, in fact my program is trying to connect to a daemon program which listens on node045:41789, but the daemon program exits at the same time, the connected port is 41789 in socket. I used the SO_REUSEADDR option in the socket, is it possible that it is related with this option.

Comment: Yes, it is very possible and likely the cause of the issue. This is why I wrote a long posting 3 days ago, mentioning that SO_REUSEADDR is more dangerous than people realize.

Comment: @SergeyA, where is the link of your post?